# Error while inheriting std::vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I am trying to define an inherited class from std::vector class. Below is the code

```
 template<class t>
 class Vector:vector<t>
 {
   public:
    using vector<t>::vector;
 };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    Vector<int> v;
    return 0;
 }
```

And I am getting error like this:

```
   "error: 'std::vector<t, std::allocator<_CharT> >::vector' names constructor"
```

So basically I would like to know why my program is failing and what all procedures to be overloaded in the my inherited class from parent std::vector class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When inheriting from `std::vector` note that it does not have to define a virtual destructor. As such, inheriting from it is not normally considered to be a good idea.

Comment: What GCC version and options?

Comment: @Bathsheba It is private inheritance, so I doubt the lack of a virtual destructor matters.

Comment: Your code is fine if you `#include <vector>` and say `using std::vector;` or call it `std::vector`. See [here](http://ideone.com/shPitZ). Also, you don't need the `using vector<t>::vector;`.

Comment: @KeillRandor public isn't relevant here.

Comment: True in this particular case. The OP should also not tie their class down to a particular instance of STL. That can be difficult to achieve.

Comment: I read in several places, that the standard containers are not meant to serve as a base class. They dont have a virtual constructor and there may be other reasons (that I am not aware of). I would use composition instead of inheritance, which anyway often leads to a nicer design.

Comment: @tobi303 presumably you mean virtual *destructor*? There's no such thing as a virtual constructor.

Comment: @Bathsheba haha, yes of course, stupid typo ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba *"should ... not tie their class down to a particular instance of STL"* - assertions without supporting arguments aren't much use to anyone.

Comment: @tobi303: if you go back and look at those "several places" you'll likely see they're talking about public inheritance....  If you have specific arguments relevant to the exact code posted, please mention them.

Comment: @TonyD Actually I dont have more than the vague memory that I read something about it, otherwise I would have mentioned specific arguments ;). Maybe there arent any and I guess you are right, that only public inheritance is a problem. Thanks for clarifying. Nevertheless I would prefer composition over inheritance with the stl containers, but again I cannot give good arguments other than my personal preference.

Comment: @tobi303 Some would argue private inheritance *is* composition.

Comment: @tobi303: Mashall Cline's FAQ addresses the question [here](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance#priv-inherit-vs-compos), but sadly omits significant benefits of private inheritance.  Specifically, you can invoke base-class functions without a `member_variable.` prefix: the concision and cleanliness of that is sometimes worthwhile.  And, private inheritance can also usefully emphasise the base class's key role when providing the primary implementation / context / data & API for the derived class: it "feels" much more like you're customising the base class behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
 #include <vector>

 template<class t>
 class Vector: std::vector<t>
 {
    public:
        using std::vector<t>::vector;
 };

 int main()
 {
    Vector<int> v;
    return 0;
 }
```

and it works fine on `gcc 4.8.` when passing the flag `-std=c++11`.

It sounds like your compiler cannot figure out what are you trying to accomplish with that `using` directive. Since inheriting constructors is a C++11 feature, I suggest you **make sure that you are running your compiler in C++11 mode**.

Comment: Sometimes you cannot change your compiler, so you have to figure out to adapt the code to the compiler